# How to merge nested stacked arrays (matrices) to CSV

Tags: jq

Is it possible to transform this JSON

```
echo -e '{"a": [[1,7],[2,6]],"b": [[1,3],[3,4]]}' | jq ...
```

In to this

```
k, a, b
1, 7, 3
2, 6, -
3, -, 4
```

Specifically the first column is the join key.

Comment: Do all arrays have all the join keys?

Comment: not necessarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yor data is structured column-first, but the table's linewise output follows a row-first stream. You basically want to transpose on objects.

Do it manually, and collect and iterate through columns and rows (using `jq -r`):

```bash
keys_unsorted as $cols | .[] |= INDEX(first) | ["k"] + $cols, (
  (map(keys[]) | unique)[] as $row
  | [$row, $cols[] as $col | .[$col][$row][1] // "-"]
)
| join(", ")  # or | @csv
```

```
k, a, b
1, 7, 3
2, 6, -
3, -, 4
```